# Simple query using MYSQL & PHP

Tags: php, mysql, select

I am trying to do a basic MYSQL search using PHP.  I have a 2 table database (staff and pic) that I want to query and output in a tabular format. Currently, I am having trouble getting my query to pull from the database correctly. Please note that I am connecting using mysql and not mysqli. Due to project restrictions, I cannot use mysqli. Any help that can be provided would be much appreciated.

```
//queries the database tables. Takes data from two tables, staff and pic and joins     them together (innerjoin)
$query = "SELECT staff.tfid, staff.lname, staff.fname, pic.file".
 "FROM staff, pic ".
    "WHERE staff.tfid = pic.tfid";


$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

// Print out the contents of each row into a table 
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo $row['tfid']. " - ". $row['lname']. " - ". $row['fname']. " - ". $row    ['file'] ;
    echo "<br />";
```

Comment: do get any error? and what is it?

Comment: Try this: while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)). You need MYSQL_ASSOC to fetch result by column names

Comment: there's no real reason to concatenate this query.  Just put the whole thing inside one set of quotes. That will fix the typo you've introduced by piecing the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

looks like you might need a space after "pic.file"

```
$query = "SELECT staff.tfid, staff.lname, staff.fname, pic.file ".
"FROM staff, pic ".
"WHERE staff.tfid = pic.tfid";
```

Comment: It worked! It's amazing that a space in the wrong place (or lack of) breaks the code. thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Use this as your query

```
$query = "SELECT staff.tfid, staff.lname, staff.fname, pic.file "."FROM staff, pic "."WHERE staff.tfid = pic.tfid";
```

I think you are missing a space before `FROM`

Answer (score 0):

mysql_query($query) needs a second parameter $dbLink which you get when you open a db connection.

```
$dbLink = mysql_connect(...);

//...

$result = mysql_query($query,$dbLink) or die(mysql_error($dbLink));
```